# Does Improved Share Spells let you cast Enlarge Person on an animal?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, animal-companions

I understand Enlarge Person only works on humanoids. However, by using [Improved Share Spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-share-spells/) on yourself,  can your animal companion also become Enlarged?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes - from the rule you linked...

> Any non-instantaneous spell (but not any spell-like ability) you cast on yourself

and

> You may share spells in this fashion even if the spells normally do not affect creatures of that type.

So, even though Enlarge Person normally only works on humanoids, it will work on your companion, and it is a non-instantaneous spell.

Answer (score 1):

As YogoZumo said, Yes.

The main reason is that the spell is targeting the caster who is humanoid.  It is just sharing the effect.